# How do i get tags in a standard format using bass?

Tags: bass

With [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html). I see i can get mp3 tags, ogg, mp4, wma, etc. Is there a standard way to get the artist, album, etc if available no matter what kind of format the stream is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Tags](http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?z/3/tags15) BASS Add On. The description of the Add On is listed below:

> An extension producing formatted text
>   from the ID3v1/v2, OGG/FLAC, WMA,
>   APEv2, or MP4 tags of a BASS stream.
>   C/C++, Delphi, and Visual Basic APIs
>   are included.